# Empty cell can not be recognised in object type to be replace with integer in Python

Tags: python, string, dataframe, null, dtype

I have the below as part of my dataframe , `column Curr` has been built up based on other columns however I produced `column First and second` as part of `column Curr` with `spot_table['First']=spot_table['Ccy'].map(lambda x: x[0:7])` and `spot_table['Second']=spot_table['Ccy'].map(lambda x: x[8:15])`.

```
Ccy               First   Second 
AUD_USD/USD_INR   AUD_USD  USD_INR 
AUD_USD/USD_SGD   AUD_USD  USD_SGD
USD_AUD           USD_AUD
AUD_USD/USD_CNH   AUD_USD  USD_CNH
USD_AUD           USD_AUD
```

they all are based on `dtype = O` while i need them to be string. I need null cells to be recognised to be fill in with `-1` . something like : `spot_table['Second'].fillna(-1, inplace = True)`

the code will be run but unfortunately the null cells can not be recognised so it wouldn't be replaced with anything !
 and whenever i use `spot_table['Second'].isnull().any()`, the result comes out as `false`.

Can anyone help me please ????????? can you please tag anyone who is able to fix the issue please?

Cheers,
Z

[image: This is the picture of the column with white space which is related to the comment to figure it out how to use isnull() in all different scenarios for object type while it doesn't work !]

This is the picture of the column with white space which is related to the comment to figure it out how to use isnull() in all different scenarios for object type while it doesn't work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Instead of using a substring, I’m splitting the value to prepare a list and only assigning the Second column with a value if there are 2 elements in the list. Else i set it with NaN.

```
spot_table['First']=spot_table['Ccy'].map(lambda x: x.split('/')[0])
spot_table['Second']=spot_table['Ccy'].map(lambda x: x.split('/')[1] if len(x.split('/'))==2 else np.NaN)
spot_table['Second'].fillna(-1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: gosh, Thanks @Emerson ! thank you very much ! so anytime in the future if i don't want to split or replace but i need to check the column with isnull.any() but it doesn't respond what can i do ? i mean if the type is object and i want it to be string and recognisable null cells ?

Comment: It depends...If your data (eg: if its a list being converted to pandas dataframe, has None for one of the values ) it should work fine with fillNa. However i think when you use substring like you have above, the result is actually not None but an empty string whcih isnt the same.

mark the issue as solved if this answers your problem

Comment: it actually happened to me a few times, when i imported CSV files . then i tried to extract **null data** out of  a specific column which has the type as object but string look ! ana didn't work !

Comment: You need to set na_values='' when you use pandas.read_csv. This will ensure '' gets converted to NaN in the dataframe

Comment: I did use **na_values=''** . I have even used **skipinitialspace=True** in read.csv but none worked ! it just shows nan values as white space and i have no idea how return it to Nan value !!

Comment: can you paste a line in your file that has null valued data

Comment: Please add a few sentences to explain what your code is doing, so you can get more upvotes for your answer.

Comment: The code is just a small tweak of the code in the question. However instead of doing a substring, I’m splitting the value based on ‘/‘. This gives me an list. The column ‘Second’ is set with the 2nd element of the list after the split only if there are two elements in the list else it is set with an NaN value. This will enable the pandas fillna function to set the value as -1 on detecting a nan value

Comment: @Emerson I have added a picture of the object column in the data . any thought ?

Comment: aah.. this is a file that has tab or spaces as its delimiter(fixed length file  ?)...This now makes it a bit harder. You will need to indicate an null value with something in this file. In fact, even if you put a value of NA in the file for that empty column , pandas will identify it as a null value and place a NaN in the value. As long as you read the file with the option [delim_whitespace=True]

Comment: exactly right ! that's what i'm trying to do ! to let panda to recognise white space as Null and fill them in by NAN. so you mean using ** delim_whitespace=True** in my read.csv ? or i got it wrong as it doesn't work and it says **EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file** ?????

Comment: You use the delim_whitespace option in case you have a file with space as delimiter. however, you have the problem that an empty value will possibly just shift the column data in the pandas dataframe, whcih is why you will need to place some sort of value to indicate an empty value.  can you paste the command you are using to read the csv file

Comment: sure!thanks fir the time . here is the read file code: **df_TL= pd.read_csv('CYMIS.csv',skiprows=2, header=None, low_memory=False )**

Comment: try 
 df_TL= pd.read_csv('CYMIS.csv',skiprows=2, header=None, low_memory=False,delim_whitespace=True )
This should read the file. However you will need to indicate an empty column with something for pandas to identify it as a NaN value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210769/discussion-between-z-a-and-emerson).

Comment: but this is exactly what i've done as i said and it gave me that emtydataerror ! i didn't get the point of an empty column ? you mean adding a column with having some empty cells manually to data before reading it ?

Comment: Based on your file I think u are better off using read_fwf where u can specify column widths.